# py2exe close window/console after exectuion

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

I convert my python script to exe file with using `py2exe`. After execution window/console has been still open.

```
from distutils.core   
import setup  
import py2exe

setup(options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}}, windows=[{'script':'WebTime_auto.py'}])
```

Is there some option, parameter to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you should try below code.

```
setup(console=['script_name'])
```

Also if you provide more details about your problem and what are trying to do then it would be good.Check this [list_of_option_for_py2exee](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) so according to this

> console  --->list of scripts to convert into console exes 
>   windows   ---->list of scripts to convert into GUI exes

Please note that if you want to make an installer you need to use innosetup or an equivalent.